# Dynamic SSH tunnel using ruby

Tags: ruby, ssh, tunnel, net-ssh, ssh-tunnel

I would like to transform this unix command into a ruby script

```
ssh -2 -f -c blowfish -N -C user@ip -D 8080
```

This is to enable all my web traffic to be encrypted in a ssh tunnel.

I tried with net-ssh library without success.

EDIT:

Here is what I tried :

```
 Net::SSH.start("my-ssh-server", "login") do|ssh|
   ssh.forward.local(8080, "localhost", 80)
   puts "Connected !"
   ssh.loop(0) { true }
 end
```

Here is the documentation of Net:SSH
http://net-ssh.rubyforge.org/ssh/v1/chapter-6.html#s4
I think, I should use Direct Channels instead of Local-to-Remote.
But the method session.forward.direct_channel is not implemented.

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: Show what you wrote using `Net::SSH` and maybe we can figure out what was wrong.

Comment: I added the example. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: Nope, sorry. I ended with a not ruby solution :-)

Answer (score -2):

Stupid and simple:

```
fork("ssh -2 -f -c blowfish -N -C user@ip -D 8080")
```

Why not that way?

Comment: Yep I already did that, but I would like to implemente that in Ruby :)